# What does DIN 985 refer to?

Tags: fastener

DIN 985 is standard issued by the DIN in Germany.

In this case it is for a simple nut [found here](https://www.fastenal.com/products/details/1L2550000A20000).

This is a follow up to this question from [bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/65828/what-does-the-din-number-refer-to).

I Googled DIN 985 but found nothing comprehensible.

These nuts and bolts are to secure aluminum so I tagged this aluminum but if there is a better tag please edit.

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE. The answer to your question on the Bicycles.SE site seems to have fully answered the question you are asking here. What additional information are you seeking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIN 985 appears to be the old name for what is now called ISO 7040 
Which describes hex nuts with a nonmetallic insert, stating their dimensions etc.

If there a likelyhood of exposure to dampness I would reccomend using aluminium or stainless steel fasteners.

Comment: Can you provide a link that shows DIN 985 is the equivalent of ISO 7040 and break down what it covers?  Thanks!

Comment: http://www.fasteners.eu/standards/DIN/985/ indicates that ISO 7040 is an "equivalent norm" to DIN 985. Is that sufficient?